# How to typeset a matrix with MathJax?

Tags: matrices, delimiters, mathjax

I need to typeset a matrix with square brackets as delimiters for [math.se](https://math.stackexchange.com/) (I believe they use MathJaX). How would I do that?

Comment: `$\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}$` works

Comment: @egreg How would I put multiple values in the same row?

Comment: `$\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix}$`, just like LaTeX with amsmath

Comment: You can also find a suitable example and see its source code by clicking `edit`. [Here is an old example](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56771/) that I found at a quick glance to my answers while I was active in there and has many matrices in it.

Comment: You can also right click on an equation, Show Math As → TeX commands.

Answer (score 54):

MathJax seems to accept the standard amsmath syntax

```
$\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix}$
```

Rows are terminated with `\\` and columns are separated by `&`

Comment: The  [Chapter 4.1 matrices of amsmath](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf)  explains the options for matrices. There is also `smallmatrix` enviroment which allows to use the matrices inline with text `$\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix}$`

Comment: For anyone looking, this is a working link of @RubenLaguna's comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20180619212427/ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf

Answer (score 15):

The curved brace matrix in Mathjax is:

```
$$\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\\ c & d\end{pmatrix}$$
```

[image]

---

Note: I used the wrapper `\color{#C00}{ <code goes here>  }` to format it in this dark red color :)

Answer (score 10):

MathJax comes with a configuration file that includes all the most general of the pre-defined configurations. It loads all the important MathJax components, including the TeX and MathML preprocessors and input processors, the AMSmath, AMSsymbols etc. So what you do you write in a similar fashion to a normal TeX file.

```
  $\begin{matrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{matrix}$
```

Whenever you get stuck do a search on wikipedia and view the equation in the editor tab. Most of the wiki mark-up will work straight with MathJax.