# Help me input a column vector

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, matrices

[image][image]

I'm trying to input an arrow vector (a column vector, see the picture) in an `align` environment, but it reports an error.

Can someone show me the TeX code of it in an `align` environment?

Comment: Crosspost to [LaTeX Community](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=24338&p=82698#p82697)

Comment: See also this answer on [how to typset a matrix with mathjax](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43453/44254). It uses amsmath syntax too as in some of the answers below.

Comment: Similar to [math mode - typesetting column vector - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2705/typesetting-column-vector?noredirect=1&lq=1) except this is [] square bracket instead of () parentheses.

Answer (score 65):

You can use `bmatrix` from `amsmath` with `\vdots`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \begin{align}
    y &= \begin{bmatrix}
           x_{1} \\
           x_{2} \\
           \vdots \\
           x_{m}
         \end{bmatrix}
  \end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image: the matrix y]

Answering to the comment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \begin{align}
    y &= (x_{1},x_{2},\cdots, x_{N})
        \begin{pmatrix}
          \begin{bmatrix}
           ax_{0} + bx_{1} \\           
           \vdots \\
           ax_{n-1}+bx_{n}
          \end{bmatrix} -
          \begin{bmatrix}
           z_{1} \\
           \vdots \\
           z_{n}
         \end{bmatrix}
    \end{pmatrix}
  \end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!My problem is if it's part of matrix calculation,like an arrow multiply it,how should I input?

Comment: @dream_big; Sorry I didn't follow. You mean multiply this matrix with another matrix? Can you add a picture?

Comment: okay,I'm writing it down and take a pic of it.

Comment: ;i have uploaded a pic,pls have a look

Comment: @dream_big: I have updated the answer.

Comment: IMHO, semantically the usage of `pmatrix` is wrong because it will produce `1x1` matrix that cannot be multiplied by the row `(x_1,..,x_N)` matrix on the left.

Comment: I'm really grateful,it has generated the desired answer

Comment: u guys r unbelievable,can recommend some related material for me on vector and matrix input

Comment: Mathmode by Herbert and amsmath manual.

Comment: @dream_big If the answers are useful, you may consider accepting them, besides upvoting. :-)

Comment: how to accept them...sorry,I'm a newcomer

Comment: @dream_big On the left side of answers, there are arrows (pen nib like). Click the up arrow for upvoting. In the middle of arrows, there is a gray check (tick) mark. Click to accept. You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 12):

A recommended solution. Adapt it to suit your need.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt,varwidth]{standalone}% change this setting back to \documenctclass{article}!
\usepackage{amsmath}

\def\A{
\begin{bmatrix}
    x_1 & x_2 & \cdots & x_N
\end{bmatrix}}

\def\B{
\begin{bmatrix}
    ax_0 + bx_1 \\
    ax_1 + bx_2 \\
    \vdots \\
    x_{N-1} + x_N
\end{bmatrix}}

\def\C{
\begin{bmatrix}
    z_1 \\
    z_2 \\
    \vdots \\
    z_N
\end{bmatrix}}

\begin{document}
\abovedisplayskip=0pt\relax% don't use this line in your production!
\begin{equation}
y =\A \left(\B - \C\right)
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Suggestions:

- Avoid using `{}` for a one-digit number `(0, 1, 2, ..., 9)`, a Latin letter `(a, b, c, ..., z)`, a Greek letter such as `(\alpha, \beta, \gamma, ...)` as a subscript (or superscript). For example, `x_{2}` should be written as `x_2`, `x_{N}` should be written as `x_N` and `x_{\alpha}` should be written as `x_\alpha`. It makes the code not only easy to read but also save more keystrokes. Note from @egreg: `x_{\notin}` cannot be written as `x_\notin`. Note from me: `x_{\sin}` cannot be written as `x_\sin`.
- For the sake of consistency, use the same bracket for column and row vectors. For example, `(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_N)` should be written as `\begin{bmatrix} x_1 & x_2 & \cdots & x_N\end{bmatrix}`.
- If you have just one line of equation with an equation number, use `equation` instead of `align`.
- Use `def` or `newcommand` (recommended) to decompose complicated equations into several reusable parts such that the complicated equations become easy to read and the smaller parts can be reused consistently everywhere in your documents.

Comment: I don't agree that `x_N` is better than `x_{N}`. I believe the exact opposite.

Comment: @egreg: Why do you believe the opposite is better?

Comment: Try `$A_\notin$`

Comment: @egreg: Is there any example that is not an function (such as `\sin`), or relation (such as `\notin`)?

Comment: @StiffJokes Most personal macros would require braces.

Answer (score 0):

for such input you can use package {simples-matrices}

```
\usepackage{simples-matrices}
\matrice(b)[1]{$z_1, z_2,\dots, z_n$}
y=\matrice(b)[4]{$x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n$}
```

the (b) provides bracket on matrices, [n] gives n cols of matrix. (check package documentation on ctan).
which sometimes you will need to format and adjust spacing, while personally I do feel this package makes things easier.